# ngClass and ngIf condition fail to compile when aot is set to true

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8, angular-aot

I have a div with a ngClass condition:

```
<div [ngClass]="{ 'active': nbActive === 1 }" >
    <!-- some stuff -->
</div>
```

And a similar div with a ngIf condition:

```
<div *ngIf="nbActive === 1">
    <!-- some stuff -->
</div>
```

Below is the NbActive declaration:

```
export class WhyChooseUsComponent implements OnInit {
   nbActive: 0;
   constructor() { }
   // some stuff
}
```

If in my production configuration, I set:

```
"aot": true,
"buildOptimizer": true,
```

Then I get the following error:

> This condition will always return 'false' since the types '0' and '1' have no overlap.

I don't get any error if I set `aot` and `buildOptimizer` to `false` and everything is working as expected.

Where does this issue come from and how can I fix this?

Comment: can you show `isActive` declaration

Comment: question edited. I renamed isActive to nbActive in order to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote

```
   nbActive: 0;
```

Which means the only acceptable value for nbActive is 0.

You might needed this instead:

```
   nbActive: number = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
<div [ngClass]="isActive === 1 ? 'active': '' " >
    <!-- some stuff -->
</div>

<div *ngIf="isActive">
    <!-- some stuff -->
</div>
```